# HttpSession & ServletContext not giving desired outcome

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to servlet.  My code executes without errors but i don't get the desired outcome.

```
@WebServlet(description = "A simple", urlPatterns = { "/SimpleServlet" })
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter wr = response.getWriter();
        String uname = request.getParameter("unam");
        HttpSession ses = request.getSession(); 
        ServletContext cont = request.getServletContext();

        if (uname != "" && uname != null)

        {
            ses.setAttribute("userses", uname); 
            cont.setAttribute("userses", uname);
        }

        wr.println("In RequestHttp method your name is "+ uname);
        wr.println("In Sesssion method  your name is " + (String)ses.getAttribute("userses"));
        wr.println("In Context  method  your name is " + (String)cont.getAttribute("userses"));
    }

}
```

So when i run in Eclipse IDE the below

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet?unam=1
```

Result

```
In RequestHttp method your name is 1
In Sesssion method your name is 1
In Context method your name is 1
```

Nothing wrong with this.

So when I run in chrome the below

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet
```

Result

```
In RequestHttp method your name is null
In Sesssion method your name is null
In Context method your name is null
```

I am expecting *Context Method your name is 1*.

I went back to Eclipse IDE and this time i did this below

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet
```

Result

```
In RequestHttp method your name is null
In Sesssion method your name is null
In Context method your name is null
```

Here I am expecting *Session method is 1*.

What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: Are you sending 3 consecutive http requests or restarting the server every time?

Comment: `uname != ""` is wonky. The `if` statement should have precisely been `if (uname != null && !uname.equals("")){...}`.

Comment: Looks one of these: you have deployed your servlet without the `if (uname ...)` validation (where you should do `!"".equals(uname)` instead using `==`) or you're restarting the server per test.

Comment: Entered unam=1 in IDE and clicked first time. then opened the chrome and did step 2 by clicking once. Came back to Eclipse and did the 3. and clicked again.  I think it should be only 3.

Comment: This works as expected for me. If you hit it with different browsers, the only thing that will change is the `HttpSession` value. The `ServletContext` value is global. If you set it once, that's the value you will see every time after that.

Comment: @Tiny I tried like your recommendation but it did not work if(uname != null && uname.equals("")){
   ses.setAttribute("userses", uname); 
   cont.setAttribute("userses", uname);
  }

Comment: no difference the output is still the same.

Comment: I get the desired result, when I give a URL like `http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet?unam=1`.

Comment: @Sotirios Your statement is the concept I agree and I want the same as an output but it is not working.  I think i have an NPE.  But even after redoing the code as per the others recommendation of the output still the same.

Comment: @Sathish NPE? Check your logs.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza thanks now the ServletContext is working in my Chrome.   After the recommendation but the HttpSession is still null when http://localhost:8080/SimpleServletProject/SimpleServlet

Comment: We can't reproduce this, is there anything else in your environment that may be interfering? Can you clarify your steps in your question?

Comment: @Tiny thanks the issue was the Eclipse IDE which is not giving the desired outcome but i tried in chrome and Explorer and both HttpSession and ServletContext worked perfect.  If anyone knows why the behaviour of eclipse like this it would be great!  Anyway all sorted thanks.

Comment: For me is simple: **never** trust in the Eclipse internal browser, it just give me more problems than solutions (and worst since in Windows it uses IE =\). Solution: use real world browsers e.g. Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: Eclipse is just an IDE. If you have deployed the application correctly on the server then, there should not be an issue. You may have forgotten to (re)build the application.

Comment: Thank you all for your advise.